# How to position social media icons using @media for max width?

Tags: html, css

I created 5 social media icons, which I centered in the middle of the page, which are all situated next to each other on the same line. I want the social media icons to be aligned to the left margin of the page and displayed underneath each other when the window size is reduced. I tried the following code but it didn't work.(When I reduce the size of the window, the icons align underneath each other but are still centered in the middle of the page, I want them aligned to the left.)

```css
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .bars2 {
    display: block;
  }
  .social {
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .social .fa {
    display: block;
  }
}

.fa {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: #7E7791;
  background: white;
}

#social {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="social" class="social">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube-play"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a live view, like a fiddle or codepen. Also adding an image of an expected result might help you getting to your answer

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO A snippet has been added, however you can't see the icons because I am using font awesome.  When you click 'Run code snippet', you will see the circles stacked on top of one another, and I want them to be against the left margin, right now they are more to the center. However this should only be when the window size is reduced.

Comment: its better to put an <i> tag inside the anchor and give it the font awesome class. not so good to use it directly in <a> tag. also its better to not change fontawesome classes directly. better to use .social > a instead of .fa in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your style look good. The problem is with your selectors, 2 main problems

1- You need to put media querys at the bottom of your document. Remember css is a cascading language and will give priority to the last style.

2- Once you did the 1st point, css also gives priority to the style depending of the level of the selectors. You gave a value of `auto` with the id selector, and a value of `0` to the class selector. This gives priority to de id selector. Therefor you dont get that `0` value

Hope thi helps :)

```css
.fa {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: #7E7791;
  background: white;
}

#social {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .bars2 {
    display: block;
  }
#social {
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .social .fa {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="social" class="social">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube-play"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I placed the `@media` query after your remaining selectors so it is not overriden. Also, I created a new id selector to override the margins set previously:

```
#social {
  margin: 10% 0 0 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```css
.fa {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: #7E7791;
  background: white;
}

#social {
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .bars2 {
    display: block;
  }
  .social {
    left: 0;
  }
  .social .fa {
    display: block;
  }
  
  #social {
    margin: 10% 0 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="social" class="social">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube-play"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set `margin-left: auto;` instead you should set it left.